# How to reset the System Tray to the default appearance on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, notification-area

I'm using Bootcamp on Macbook Pro 2011.

Recently I installed some software call Trackpad++ and it reset something on my desktop, and I have uninstalled it and reset most of the stuff to the default.

Now the only thing I couldn't find a way to make it the way it use to be where I will have an arrow to press and will see most of the stuff inside it.

This is what it is look like now.
[image]

Comment: I didn't know Win8 worked in bootcamp. Cool.

Comment: @WarrenP Yes it since Windows 8 it is out, but now it is official from Apple with bootcamp 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the taskbar clock, click *Customize notification icons*. A new window will open, uncheck *Always show all icons and notifications on taskbar* at the bottom. Done.

Comment: WOW!! I have been to this place for 5 times and really didn't try to uncheck that... WOW